# QT C++ - Marker based augmented Reality

Tags: qt, 3d, marker, aruco

I'm detecting markers by using aruco;

```
   std::vector<int> ids;
   std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;

    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(image, dictionary, corners, ids);
    if (ids.size() > 0)
        cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(imageCopy, corners, ids);
```

In order to use drawDetectedMarkers method, I would like to add 3d object on the marker. I looked at similar projects which are implemented in C# language. I took their unity object.However I'm not sure which is the best way to put any 3D object on the marker. Should I use openscenegraph or opengl? I can use marker board also for this process. I obtained rvec( rotation vector of the board) and tvec (translation vector of the board) values in real time. It's my first time in 3d object - QT. I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize OpenCV Viz library for 3D visualization. Actually OpenCV Viz is a simplified version of OpenSceneGraph. If you have OpenCV 2.4 or later, Viz is default. It supports Mesh files in OBJ and PLY formats. You can transform 3D objects in Viz using the rvec/tvec outputs of ARUCO. You can take a look at my post for a sample code snippet. ([Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484721/how-to-transform-a-3d-model-for-augmented-reality-application-using-opencv-viz-a)) Click [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/viz/table_of_content_viz/table_of_content_viz.html) for OpenCV 2.4 version, or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/df9/tutorial_table_of_content_viz.html) for 3.1 version.